# Optimize Ruby detect statement

Tags: ruby

Here is a kind of `switch` statement with default value:

```
def test(st)
  [[2, 'info'],
   [3, 'warning'],
   [4, 'danger'],
   [5, 'success']].detect(Proc.new{[nil, 'default']}){|el| el[0]==st}[1]
end
```

How to make this statement more compact?

I do not like several things:

- an sub-array is returned from detect instead of returning it's second element
- the default value is defined as `[nil, 'default']` instead of simple `'default'`
- the default value has to be wrapped into `Proc.new`

Comment: Any reason not to use a `case` statement?

Comment: @sawa: `a = test(self.current_state)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Hash` data-structure and take the advantage of the method [`#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)

```
def test(st)
  { 2 => 'info', 3 => 'warning',
    4 => 'danger',5 => 'success'
  }.fetch(st,'default')
end
```

Here is the documentation :-

> Returns a value from the hash for the given key. If the key can’t be found, there are several options: With no other arguments, it will raise an `KeyError` exception; if *default* is given, then that will be returned; if the *optional code block* is specified, then that will be run and its result returned.

Comment: There is a trend: people with more reputation catch the point without any additional questions :) Thank you! Amazing answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Hash to make it look up the value directly. Then you can also take advantage of the Hash's default value ability, by passing `default` into `new`.

```
def test(st)
  map = Hash.new('default')
  map.merge!({
    2 => 'info',
    3 => 'warning',
    4 => 'danger',
    5 => 'success'
  })
  map[st]
end
```

I would also suggest you only create the `map` hash once, somewhere outside of the `test` method, its wasteful to keep creating it each time `test` is called.